# Why each table in function gives wrong results - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I m trying to get `id` on `keyup` of input of td tag every cell of the table but it gives only the first id of first column and row on keyup of every input.How do i fix this?

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".typeahead_3", function() {
  var $table = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
  $('#' + $table + '> tbody  > tr').each(function() {

    var ast_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=ast_id]").val();
    var asset_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=asset_id]").val();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=employee_id]").attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    $('#' + id).typeahead(null, {
      source: [{
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "code": "AF",
        "ccn0": "040"
      }, {
        "name": "Land Islands",
        "code": "AX",
        "ccn0": "050"
      }, {
        "name": "Albania",
        "code": "AL",
        "ccn0": "060"
      }, {
        "name": "Algeria",
        "code": "DZ",
        "ccn0": "070"
      }]
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://t0m.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/0.10.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="job-card">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>JOb ID</td>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>date</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2"><b>Mini Paver</b></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="3"><b>035m planner</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">MP01</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">MP02</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/1</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/2</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>C R MacDonald Ltd</td>
      <td>11/01/2018</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="29" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="5" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type295">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="20" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="7" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type207">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="12" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="2" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type122">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="16" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="1" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type161">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="18" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="6" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type186">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>National Road Planing Ltd (Thatcham)</td>
      <td>11/01/2018</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="22" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="1" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type221">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="25" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="12" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type2512">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="36" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="24" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type3624">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="17" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="9" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type179">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="11" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="13" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type1113">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the js fiddle  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rks5oq4x/)

any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you want to get the `id` of the input ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the following code

```
 $('#' + $table + '> tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var ast_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=ast_id]").val();
    var asset_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=asset_id]").val();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=employee_id]").attr("id")
```

In the above code `$(this)` is not actually referring the keyup element. It is referring `$('#' + $table + '> tbody  > tr')` element. It means it always going to the first row element and giving you the same id always.

It is very simple to get the things but you make it complex on your code. Look at the following code.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".typeahead_3", function() {
   var ast_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=ast_id]").val();
   var asset_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=asset_id]").val();
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=employee_id]").attr("id");
   console.log(id);
   $('#' + id).typeahead(null, {
     source: [{
       "name": "Afghanistan",
       "code": "AF",
       "ccn0": "040"
     }, {
       "name": "Land Islands",
       "code": "AX",
       "ccn0": "050"
     }, {
       "name": "Albania",
       "code": "AL",
       "ccn0": "060"
     }, {
       "name": "Algeria",
       "code": "DZ",
       "ccn0": "070"
     }]
   });
});
```

In the above you can directly get the colsest `tr` and get all the information as you expected.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rks5oq4x/11/)

**EDIT**

After seeing your comment, I came to know you have used the same id for all the places. In that case, find the closest `td` instead of `tr` then you will get the expected results.

```
var ast_id = $(this).closest('td').find("input[name=ast_id]").val();
var asset_id = $(this).closest('td').find("input[name=asset_id]").val();
var id = $(this).closest('td').find("input[name=employee_id]").attr("id");
```

[**UDPATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rks5oq4x/13/)

Comment: Still it gives the same ids for every input:(

Comment: i have updated my answer. check it out EDIT section and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you want from your code, but to get the `id` of the current `input` field, you simply can get the `id` attribute of `$(this)`.

```js
$(".typeahead_3").on("keyup", function() {
  var inputTxt = $(this);
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var thisTD = inputTxt.closest("td"); //This is the current <td>
  var ast = (thisTD.find("input[name=ast_id]")).val();
  var asset = (thisTD.find("input[name=asset_id]")).val();
  console.log('id = '+id+', ast = '+ast+', asset = '+asset);
  /* The rest of your code */
});
```

```html
<link href="http://t0m.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/0.10.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="job-card">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>JOb ID</td>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>date</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2"><b>Mini Paver</b></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="3"><b>035m planner</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">MP01</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">MP02</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/1</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/2</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">035/3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>C R MacDonald Ltd</td>
      <td>11/01/2018</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="29" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="5" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type295">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="20" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="7" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type207">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="12" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="2" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type122">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="16" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="1" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type161">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="18" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="6" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type186">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>National Road Planing Ltd (Thatcham)</td>
      <td>11/01/2018</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="22" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="1" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type221">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="25" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="12" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type2512">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="36" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="24" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type3624">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="17" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="9" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type179">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="11" name="ast_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="13" name="asset_id">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control typeahead_3" id="type1113">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works. Could you just tell me how can i get other two inputs values without using each function?

Comment: Wich " other two inputs values"?

Comment: Can you see two input tags are there for each td? named as `ast_id` and `asset_id` ?